# Bash variable assignment and command not found

Tags: bash, shell, variables, cygwin

I have a shell script that will let me access global variables inside the script, but when I try to create my own, it responds with: command not found.

```
#!/bin/bash
J = 4
FACE_NAME = "eig$J.face"
USER_DB_NAME = "base$J.user"
```

When I run the above script I get:

```
./test1.sh line 2: J: command not found
./test1.sh line 3: FACE_NAME: command not found
./test1.sh line 4: USER_DB_NAME: command not found
```

Any ideas?? I'm using Cygwin under Windows XP.

Comment: Don't use all CAPS in your variable names when creating variables. By convention, environment variables (PATH, EDITOR, SHELL, ...) and internal shell variables
(BASH_VERSION, RANDOM, ...) are fully capitalized. All other variable names should be
lowercase. Since variable names are case-sensitive, this convention avoids accidentally
overriding environmental and internal variables.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Try this (notice I have removed the spaces from either side of the `=`):

```
#!/bin/bash
J="4"
FACE_NAME="eig$J.face"
USER_DB_NAME="base$J.user"
```

Bash doesn't like spaces when you declare variables - also it is best to make every value quoted (but this isn't as essential).

Comment: Oh man, that is so depressing. That was my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Andrew Hare. Just had the same depressing problem!

Comment: I really don't understand why bash doesn't accept space :(

Comment: I was about to pray God! Tears...

Comment: "notice I have removed the spaces from either side of the = " <- This is the simplest yet most useful solution I have seen recently.

Comment: I have something similar but not working still. WTF?

Comment: Thank you for this simple yet, obvious solution.  Just need to learn syntax of bash better.

Comment: I don't know how this is hard to understand. If you put spaces, you're telling bash to do it's JOB and run a command. Variables are the exception to the rule, not commands.

"But why can't bash just accept spaces after variable name." If you're still somehow asking this, then imagine this: `echo = hi` - this should print `= hi` to the terminal, but if we went by the suggested logic, this would instead set a variable named `echo` to `hi`.

Answer (score 12):

It's a good idea to use braces to separate the variable name when you are embedding a variable in other text:

```
#!/bin/bash
J=4
FACE_NAME="eig${J}.face"
USER_DB_NAME="base${J}.user"
```

The dot does the job here for you but if there was some other character there, it might be interpreted as part of the variable name.

Comment: Using {} to delimit variables in the middle of text is a best practice for shell programming.

Comment: This was my problem! The first solution didn't work for me, but this did.

Answer (score 7):

dont' leave spaces between "="

```
J=4
FACE_NAME="eig${J}.face"
USER_DB_NAME="base${J}.user"
```